# Java: What is the absolut first second in Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar

For example I have this:

```
Calendar result = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
result.setTime(new Date(0))
```

This should be the start of Calendar (1. Januar 1970 ...), but what is really the first second since epoche? Or more precise: What timezone with 0 milliseconds since epoche is the earliest?

Is it "Pacific/Kiritimati" the first?

Comment: Loop through the timezones, use a SimpleDateFormat with the pattern yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss to print the epoch in each of the time zones, and find the "earliest" string among them.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets

Comment: Are you asking what's the earliest possible time that can be represented in a Java `Date`?  If that's what you're asking, it's about 292 million years ago; due to the magic of negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise UTC is not a timezone, it is a time standard. To be formally correct no country/territory is using UTC "timezone". But from a very basic view UTC is similar to GMT. So first second since epoche is one second after midnight in GMT (in 1.1.1970).

Also note, that countries that use GMT switch to different timezone when they apply daylight saving time. E.g. UK switches BST which is +01:00 from GMT

Comment: Then init the calandar with timezone 'Etc/GMT-14' is the earliest possible time? For example the first silvester in the world for java?

Comment: It seems that you slightly misunderstand meaning of timezone. The information about the earliest (zero) time is given by new Date(0). If you init calendar by this, then you have really 0 time. Setting a timezone on calendar instance only tells you what is local time of that one exact point in time. So new Date(0) is 00:00 in GMT, 01:00 in CET...etc. But it is still the same timepoint (01:00 in CET is 0 time)

Comment: and where in the world do you have the first seconds in new year and what timezone is this? Is it "Etc/GMT-14"?

Comment: In other words: Epoch time (0) started when there was a midnight in UK, 01:00 in central europe, 02:00 in Turkey... etc. But it was still the same point in the time. In epoch time start, they celebrated New Year in UK but it was already one hour after celebrations in central europe. New year is not celebrated the "same time" (meaning same point in time) over the world. Japanese and Europeans don't do the countdown in same time :-)

Comment: Then people in timezone Etc/GMT-14 have already 14 oclock, when people in GMT celebrate the new year? Is this right?But is Etc/GMT-14 the first?

Comment: If you mean UTC+14:00 (that Kiritimati) then you are correct. They are about to wake up after wild night and in the same time, people are starting to celebrate in UK. And yes, they are the first who celebrate New year in the world.

Comment: Im confused about the TimeZoneID, and the displayedName. I get "Etc/GMT-14 GMT+14:00" if I sysout the TimeZoneID & TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneID).getDisplayName(). But I think we both mean the same.

Comment: yes, we mean the same, it is that Kiritimati timezone